# Where does dprintf(INFO...) or dprintf(CRITICAL...) go in Android LK

Tags: android, arm, embedded, driver, qualcomm

I'm working on a project that is using an Intrinsyc OpenQ-2500 development kit. The kit uses an APQ8909W snapdragon processor, which is running a modified version of Oreo 8.1.

I'm attempting to bring up a new 2-lane MIPI display we've connected. I've roughly followed the steps outlined in one of Intrinsycs display porting guide: https://developer.qualcomm.com/download/db410c/dsi-display-porting-guide-linux-android.pdf

This has been unsuccesful and we are know debugging. In one of the files that required configuring for the new display there are some dprintf() lines as shown below:

```
if (panel_override_id < 0) {
    dprintf(CRITICAL, "Not able to search the panel:%s\n",
                panel_name);
} else if (panel_override_id < UNKNOWN_PANEL) {
    /* panel override using fastboot oem command */
    panel_id = panel_override_id;

    dprintf(INFO, "OEM panel override:%s\n",
            panel_name);
    goto panel_init;
}
```

As I understand it INFO or CRITICAL is a debug level, according to debug.h:

```
#if defined(DEBUG)
#define DEBUGLEVEL DEBUG
#else
#define DEBUGLEVEL 2
#endif

/*debug levels*/
#define CRITICAL 0
#define ALWAYS 0
#define INFO 1
#define SPEW 2
```

Can anyone tell me where the actual output of the dprintf() would be directed to?

Comment: Not Linux related. LK is a separate kernel that Qualcomm and others use as an Android bootloader; it runs before Linux starts. You should look into how to configure a serial console for your board.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. That output has to go somewhere though right? Setting my own custom output was plan B but I was hoping to find a log file somewhere.

Comment: The output goes to serial console. https://developer.qualcomm.com/qfile/29222/lm80-p0436-24_connect_uart_to_usb_adapterapp_note.pdf

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thanks!